# How to configure atop sampling interval & log path?

Tags: atop

I installed `atop` version 1.26 on Ubuntu 12.04 server. By default, its sampling interval is 10 minutes. How can I change to 1 minute?

Also, how can I set the log path? Currently the logs are at `/var/log/`, but I notice that `atop` added a folder `/var/log/atop/` (empty). How can I set the logs to be saved in this folder?

Comment: Adding this here since I have been searching for this *forever*, and this question has popped up consistently: On *Ubuntu*, the log retention time for atop logs is "hard"-coded into atop init.d script, you can find the line by searching for `find` within the script (default should be `+28`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction:  the default sampling interval for `atop` is 10 seconds; `atop` writes compressed binary data to */var/log/atop/atop_YYYYMMDD* every 10 minutes.

Sampling intervals and log file locations can be set from the command line.  To set the sample interval to one minute:

```
atop 60
```

Set compressed raw format log to *foo.log*:

```
atop -w foo.log
```

Comment: but how to change the log path to `/var/log/atop/foo.log` ?

Comment: @Raptor, do we need to?  Find out with:  `ps -A atop && lsof -p $(pidof atop) | grep log`

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer I believe  it misses the point of the question which is about *configuring* atop with non-default settings and not *running* atop with non default settings.

Comment: @ndemou, Perhaps it is about configuring and not running `atop`, and [*Rifaideen*'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397902/165517) is more correct.  If that is so, then the question should be revised, so that its wording makes the *OP*'s true intent obvious.  *OTOH*, the *OP* did accept this answer, so I dunno.  "Plan B" would be to just ask another question about how to change `atop` log file location & default duration.

Answer (score 8):

1. Edit the file `/etc/default/atop`
2. SET `INTERVAl=60`
3. SET `LOGPATH="/ur-desired-path"`, in this case `LOGPATH="/var/log/atop"`
4. Restart the `atop` service `systemctl restart atop.service`

P.S.  In *Centos 7* I have `atop`'s config file in  */etc/sysconfig/atop*.

Comment: Content of /etc/default/atop: "# this file is no longer used and will be removed in a future release". Would you know where is the new file?

Comment: According to atop [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/atop), it is now configurable using `/etc/atoprc` or `~/.atoprc`. `man atoprc` list configuration options.

Comment: Update: `atoprc` doesn't control log interval of the background job that saves these logfiles. Instead it only controls the default for interactive session. So it seems like one has to edit the file `/usr/share/atop/atop.daily` or wherever an equivalent file is on a given system.

Comment: Thanks for noting the different config path for CentOS, you'd think they'd mention this in the man pages..

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 18.04 you'd change the file `/usr/share/atop/atop.daily` and change the line:

```
INTERVAL=600
```

to:

```
INTERVAL=60
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20 the same, thank you

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16.04 you can change the sampling interval in the `/etc/default/atop` file.

To change it to sample once a minute, edit the the file and set `INTERVAL=60`

You can also edit the location of the log files by setting the `LOGPATH` variable.

After editing the defaults, restart the `atop` daemon with this command:

`systemctl restart atop.service`

Comment: this does not seem to work on Raspbian 9
`
sudo systemctl restart atop.service
sudo systemctl status atop.service
 Main PID: 1518 (atop)
   CGroup: /system.slice/atop.service
           └─1518 /usr/bin/atop -a -R -w /var/log/atop/atop_20190405 600
`
so it's still running at 10 min interval.

Also /etc/default/atop file has comment
"# this file is no longer used and will be removed in a future release"

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the values as your need on the file /etc/sysconfig/atop

mainly

```
LOGOPTS=""
LOGINTERVAL=600
LOGGENERATIONS=28
LOGPATH=/var/log/atop
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Please note, you're answering to a 7y old question with an [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). While providing new insight to old questions is perfectly fine, at this point the answer really needs to provide something essentially new. As far as I can see you're just re-hashing the 4 previous answers, so what exactly is the new thing you're bringing to the table?

Comment: Without digging too deep into the details, I notice that this new answer refer to **LOG**INTERVAL, while all older answers seem to be mentioning INTERVAL. It appears the variable was switched in commit [9628791](https://github.com/Atoptool/atop/commit/9628791). Maybe someone with deeper interest in atop could dig into that and clarify whether the rename is crucial or not?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).